# "unreasonable length" when running kafka-topics command

Tags: apache-kafka

I installed Kafka 2.4.0 and am seeing odd behavior when I run the kafka-topics.sh command.

I can start zookeeper and kafka with no issues, and when I run this

`kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:2181 --version`

I get this:
`2.4.0 (Commit:77a89fcf8d7fa018)`

So far so good. But if I try to list all the topics:

`kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:2181 --list`

the command just hangs and I see the zookeeper console spews this message repeatedly:

`WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0: Unreasonable length = 308375649`

At first I thought this may be a clash with Confluent 5.3.2, which I also had installed, but I removed that. I uninstalled Kafka, and re-installed. No joy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:2181 --list

The problem is that you are using zookeeper address as a bootstrap-server address. It shoud be like this:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --list
```

Alternatively you can also use zookeeper address too with --zookeeper parameter like this:

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --list
```

P.S: Prior to Kafka version 2.2 zookeeper is the only valid option in topics.sh, but after that both bootstrap-server and zookeeper are valid options. You can check [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-377%3A+TopicCommand+to+use+AdminClient) for more information.

Comment: Please note that the option --zookeeper was marked as deprecated and as of 3.0 is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It actually Works.